# MySQL query works in phpMyAdmin but not in java

Tags: java, mysql

I have the query

```
INSERT INTO tests2 (`name`, `val1`, `val2`, `val3`, `rotation~time`, `rotation~messages~countdown_format`, `rotation~messages~messages`) VALUES ('Testing', 'Test', 'false', '0', '21', 'Value', '[[Value 1,  Value 2]]')
```

which works fine in phpMyAdmin, but it gives a exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

when called in java using

```
statement.execute(query);
```

(I create the connection using this method:)

```
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(getJDBCString(settings.host(), settings.port(), settings.database()), settings.username(), settings.password());
        statement = connection.createStatement();
```

What is wrong?

**EDIT**:

*It is my intention to have ints and booleans saved as Strings*

*I also tried swapping the graves (`) for ' and "*

Comment: Try replacing the ` (accent grave, or something) with `'` in the java code.

Comment: Firstly, stop adding apostrophes to integer fields, they are for Strings. Secondly, provide the Java code with the query.

Comment: @MostyMostacho It is my intention to store integers as strings

Comment: If your query throws an exception then it does **not** *work fine* (simply by definition).

Comment: @PM77-1 phpMyAdmin does not complain about the query, and does what it is supposed to do (insert the row). Java throws exceptions though

Comment: Java is not throwing an exception. MySQL is throwing the exception. Java is just the innocent messenger. The fact that you are getting back a MySQL exception means your connection is fine and the issue is definitely with the query

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the values of the query are being populated with Java variables. If so, I would check that '[[Value 1,  Value 2]]' is being properly populated with a string value. The MySQL exception usually occurs right before the part of the query provided in the error message, so...

```
the right syntax to use near ')'
```

means the issue is probably either **'[[Value 1,  Value 2]]')** or **`rotation~messages~messages`)**